# Positive Measure on $[0,1]$ and Measure of a Given Set

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

I have the following problem that I'm trying to puzzle through.

> Let $\mu$ be a positive measure on $[0,1]$ with $\mu([0,1])=1$ and let $f\geq 0$ be a summable function on $[0,1]$. Suppose that $\int_{[0,1]}f~d\mu<\frac{1}{10}$. Define $X=\{x\in[0,1]~:~f(x)<1\}$. Prove that $\mu(X)\geq \frac{9}{10}$.

I know that since $\int_{[0,1]}f~d\mu$ is the supremum of all integrals $\int_{[0,1]}\psi~d\mu$, where $\psi$ is simple and $0\leq\psi\leq f$, this supremum must be less than $\frac{1}{10}$.

I was thinking that maybe I need to use the characteristic function of the set $X$ and construct some sort of sequence of simple functions to approximate $f$. But I'm not really sure if this is the right approach, or what I would need to do in this case. Any input is appreciated!

Comment: You use $X$ before defining it? It should be the same $X$?

Comment: @Shashi Nope! My mistake; I'll edit that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint.**
$$\mu(X^c) =\int_{X^c}1\ d\mu \leq  \int_{X^c} f \ d\mu \leq \int_{[0,1]}f\ d\mu< \frac 1 {10}$$
*Why do these inequalities hold? Finally, what is the relation between $\mu(X^c)$ and $\mu(X)$?*

Comment: Would we have $\mu(X^{c})+\mu(X)=1$ since $X\cup X^{c}=[0,1]$? Or am I off track?

Comment: @Sir_Math_Cat No you are on track, it is true!

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense now!

Comment: Actually, @Shashi, just a quick question. Is $\int_{X^{c}}1~d\mu$ the integral of the constant 1, or some sort of indicator function?

Comment: It is the integral of the constant $1$, but you may also write it as $\int_{[0,1]} \mathbf{1}_{X^c} \, d\mu$ where now I used the indicator function.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the clarification!

Comment: @Sir_Math_Cat glad I could help